# Calling a static method from a class in another namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, static-methods

This code bellow gives me this error : `Class 'MyNamespace\Database' not found`. How do I reference a class that belongs to no namespace, from inside one ?

```
Class Database
{
    public function request()
    {
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public function myFuction()
        {
            Database::request();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this can be solved in C++ doing `::Database::request()`, but I tried that with no success in PHP ;)

Comment: Indeed; the solution is equivalent, but in PHP the namespace "scope resolution operator" of sorts is `\ `, not `::`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try with

```
\Database::request();
```

Also see [Namespace Basics Example 1 in the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: Wow that was fast ! Thanks, it works, and it's even uglier than its C++ counterpart :p