# Problems with PHP namespaces and built-in classes, how to fix?

Tags: namespaces, php

I'm writing a small library in PHP and i'm having some problems with built-in classes not being read. For example:

```
namespace Woody;

class Test {
  public function __construct() {
    $db = new PDO(params);
  }
}
```

This gives me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Woody\PDO' not found in /var/www/test.php

Comment: This is probably the same: [How to use “root” namespace of php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593621/how-to-use-root-namespace-of-php/6593676)

Answer (score 38):

This:

```
namespace Woody;
use PDO;
```

Or:

```
$db = new \PDO(params);
```

Point in case is, that the class `PDO` is not a full qualified name within your Namespace, so PHP would look for `Woody\PDO` which is not available.

See [Name resolution rules<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) for a detailed description how class names are resolved to a *Fully qualified name*.

Comment: thanks for a better answer than my own. I knew the solution, but I didn't explain it nearly as well as you did!

Comment: The `\PDO` method doesn't work for me in `PHP 5.5.12`, but this does: `use PDO;`.

Comment: @tastro: I think as well that using `use` is good practice. Then you can see at the top of the file which classes are taken in.

Answer (score 6):

Add a backslash before class name, ie

```
$db = new \PDO(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

The below should work:

```
namespace Woody;

class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        $db = new \PDO(params);
    }
}
```

You need to prefix PDO with the backslash so PHP knows it's in the global namespace.