# Using Imagick in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, imagick

I am trying to use Imagick with Symfony2, but every time I try and use it, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Acme\TestBundle\Services\Imagick' not found...
```

I am using Imagick in a service I have setup to manage my images. What do I need to do to be able to use this class?

I can confirm the Imagick extension is working on the server and is in use by other sites.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you instantiate the Imagick class, use a full quallified class-name:

```
new \Imagick;
```

This will make PHP not look for the class `Imagick` within the current namespace.

For a more detailed explanation see a similar Question/Answer: [Problems with PHP namespaces and built-in classes, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901358/problems-with-php-namespaces-and-built-in-classes-how-to-fix/6901395#6901395) and [How to use "root" namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593621/how-to-use-root-namespace-of-php).

Comment: Genius, that is great. Thanks for such a quick answer hakre!