# How to use the 'raw' PHP Mongodb PECL driver within Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, pecl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Imagick in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109649/using-imagick-in-symfony2)

I'm new to Symfony so this might be a dummy question. But since after several hours of google I haven't found any related answer it might worth a try here.

So basically I was using Windows, Apache, pure PHP, Mongodb and the 'raw' PHP_Mongodb PECL driver (the word 'raw' is used here to differ from the Doctrine Mongodb ODM bundle in Symfony2) for web application development. The PECL driver worked perfectly fine, and I could just write something like this:

```
  <?php
  $m = new Mongo();
  $db = $m->myDB;
  $db->find();
  //Do Other DB Operations.
```

The above code worked fine without any 'use', 'include' or 'require' statements since I followed the standard instructions and setup the PECL driver extension in php.ini. When showing phpinfo() in the web browser, the Mongodb driver information shows up correctly. Everything's perfect.

Then I start to use Symfony2 because it provides url rewriting, MVC pattern, security and other useful stuff. The Doctrine Mongodb ODM bundle works nice except that, seems to me, **it can only persist PHP objects**. I do have a bunch of javascript object in my project to persist and there is simply no way of doing that except to put a 'PHP wrapper' on top of it (to create a PHP object which contains only that javascript object).

When I was trying to use the good old PECL trick to talk to the database with the same block of code above, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyProject\Controller\Mongo' not found in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Symfony\src\MyProject\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 47.
```

Seems Symfony2 blocked or overwrited the extension paths in php.ini while only looking for its auto class loader. I guess I'll need to change the autoload.php and/or AppKernel.php to include that extension? Please help me understand what's going on here. Can I use the PECL driver in Symfony2 at all? Or is Doctrine Mongodb ODM **the only way** to access database in Symfony2? Thanks!

Comment: `new \Mongo()`, let me fetch you the duplicate:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 works with namespace php. This makes working with non-namespace libraries/classes a bit tricky, but you really just need to know the tricks.

When you try to use `new Mongo()` to grab a mongodb object, PHP looks in your current namespace, which means it looks for a mongo() function within your class. To make this work, you need to specify the namespace for mongo. Since it does not use namespaces, PHP places it in the global namespace . So, to correctly reference the function, you need to use `new \Mongo()`, and PHP will look in your \ namespace instead of your current one.