# Importing class without namespace to namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces, smarty3

I have a some class, it include Smarty, but my class use namespace test, Smarty don't use namespaces.
How include Smarty, without writing namespaces into smarty files (it has many system plugins)

```
    import "smarty/Smarty.php"

    class testik
    {
        public function __construct ()
        {
            $smarty = new Smarty();
        }
    }


<?php

    class Smarty
    {
        //somcode
    }
```

Smarty has  autoloader class and include its plugins, plugins haven't namespaces too.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Tell your namespaced code it's in the global namespace:

```
$smarty = new \Smarty();
```

Additionally [importing<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) works this way:

```
use Smarty;
```

Then you can use your code as it was:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

See as well: [How to use “root” namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6593621/367456).

Comment: Lol, i fought this my namespaces, dirs, autoloader, but forgot about this

Comment: Also works when you need to call external static method/variable **inside a namespaced class** e.g. `\Handy::doGeneralStuff();`