# PHP extends doesn't work.. Class 'Smarty' not found

Tags: php, smarty, extends

I have a problem with the *`extends`* of PHP. My code in the `page.class.php`:

```
    <?php
    require_once ('globals.class.php');
    require_once ('Smarty.class.php');

    class CPage extends Smarty
    {
     .
     .
     .
```

In the `Smarty.class.php` the class name is `Smarty`.

So I don't know why I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Smarty' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\www\classes\page.class.php on line 6

Comment: are you sure `Smarty.class.php` is not empty ?

Comment: if Smarty uses namespace, you should declare class CPage extends \namespace\of\Smarty

Comment: Can you do a `echo (defined('SMARTY_DIR') ? 'Yes' : 'No');` to see if Smarty.class.php is being processed correctly? No reason why hte code should fail unless the require_once isn't being called, or is callign the "wrong" file (e.g. as Mihai said, an empty file).

Comment: echo (defined('SMARTY_DIR') ? 'Yes' : 'No'); -> answer is 'No' .. The Smarty.class.php isn't empty, the class will define there 100%. I think the answer should be 'Yes' @Robbie or? What's wrong?! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is more a comment than an actual answer:

As you use `require` I assume that the `Smarty` class has been defined.

So you are probably using namespaces, which would require you to `use` that specific class or provide a fully qualified classname (FQCN) instead:

```
class CPage extends \Smarty
                    ^- Smarty is in the global namespace in this example
```

Otherwise use the class on top:

```
Use \Smarty;
```

to import it into your current namespace.

The answer is with the pre-condition that the `Smarty` class you refer to is in the global namespace. I'm not fluent with Smarty so I do not know if it has it's own namespace yet, and if so, which one it is. So the concrete FQCN might vary.

See as well:

- [Importing class without namespace to namespaced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574794/importing-class-without-namespace-to-namespaced-class/8574832#8574832)
- [How to use “root” namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593621/how-to-use-root-namespace-of-php/6593676#6593676)
- [Name resolution rules<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)