# Using classes without namespace with Yii2

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2, 2checkout, psr-4

I want to use [Checkout SDK](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-php) with Yii2 but since this library does not support PSR-4 standards (namespaces) I am having trouble to integrate it. How can I use this library for my purpose?

**EDIT**

As suggested I tried to use class as

```
$sale = new \Twocheckout_Sale();
```

but still I am unable to make it work.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @arogachev class not found and when I try to include it manually it says cannot redeclare it

Comment: Make sure you have extension installed and it files exist in vendor folder.

Comment: @arogachev I have installed it using composer using ' "2Checkout/2checkout-php":"@stable"' under require section

Comment: Updated the answer, It should work now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the class does not have namespace it means it's in the root namespace.

**Option 1:**

```
use Twocheckout;

...

Twocheckout::format('json');
```

**Option 2:**

```
\Twocheckout::format('json');
```

For example, [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) extension also doesn't have namespaces, similar question was answered on [official forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52199-how-to-load-phpexcel-in-yii-20-project/).

Related questions:

[Importing class without namespace to namespaced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574794/importing-class-without-namespace-to-namespaced-class)

[How to use "root" namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593621/how-to-use-root-namespace-of-php)

Official PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

**Update:**

But `PHPExcel` has own autoloader, while `2Checkout` does not. All classes are included by requiring one main abstract class. It's even mentioned in official [readme](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-php):

```
require_once("/path/to/2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php");
```

So you need to manually include it before using library classes. It can be done with help of alias to avoid writing full path.

```
use Yii;
...
$path = Yii::getAlias("@vendor/2checkout/2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php");
require_once($path);
$sale = new \Twocheckout_Sale();
```

For usage in one place it's OK, but if it will be used in many places of application, it's better to require it in entry script `index.php`:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/2checkout/2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');
```

I also recommend to read tips in official documentatiton about [using downloaded libraries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-downloaded-libraries), there are more options you can use depending on the specific library.

Comment: Please see the edit . I am unable to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Try this  */
public function actionTest(){
    //package
    require(Yii::getAlias('@vendor')."/Excel/Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader.php");

    $exldata = new \Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();


}
```