# How to add manually add an extension to Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I have downloaded a library (not a Yii core extension). I want to add this libray to Yii framework 2.0.

I have read [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-extensions.html) under the section "Installing Extensions Manually" but I could not get it to work. Below is the structure of my downloaded library:

```
\mandrill
   \mandrill
       \src
           Mandrill.php
```

The `Mandrill` class lives in `Mandrill.php` and does not have a namespace. How can I add this library to Yii framework 2.0 and how to register this library's class manually?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer/30480565#30480565) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128117/using-classes-without-namespace-with-yii2/28128493#28128493) answers.