# How to call variables and functions from an external library in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I call to an external library in a fileForm in the models layer

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
include "../lib/libchart/classes/libchart.php"; //external library
```

However Yii2 does not recognize a variable from that external library, the error is: "PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException - Class 'app\models\LineChart' not found"

I have the following function in the fileForm:

`public function insertGrafic()
   {

     $chart = new LineChart();
     ...
   }`

What's missing? Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128117/using-classes-without-namespace-with-yii2

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the library as a Component in your config file.

[Write & use a custom Component in Yii2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/)

```
'components' => [
    'libchart' => [
        'class' => 'class Path',
    ],
```

Then use your component method like this:

```
Yii::$app->libchart->method();
```

Comment: I added the former 'components' statement in config\web.php and in config\console.php ('libchart' => [
    'class' => 'lib\libchart\classes\libchart.php',
   ],   ) And I get this message: "Class lib\libchart\classes\libchart.php does not exist"  What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check if the library extends the interface Component of Yii and has a valid namespace. If not, add it,  it should not change how library works.

Comment: How do I add the all third-party and create its namespace? Thanks

Comment: copy it in your project folder, you can create a special foler base/libchart for example. Then open the class file and add the namespace `namespace app\libchart`. Use the guide i've post to do it properly.

Comment: I apreciate your help. I am getting something wrong in the logic (I get this error: Namespace missing?). I created a folder base/libchart. Then I created a file libchart.php with 
class libchart extends Component {public function welcome()... Then at the model's layer I call public function insert(){Yii::$app->libchart->welcome();....}

Comment: Have you add it in your config file as a component? look the step 3 in the guida I've posted

Comment: I created a component Graphic just like the  latter link, however Where do I set the path of the external library? lib\libchart\classes\libchart.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yii2 is fully namespaced. instead of using includes you have to use namespace. based on the error message it looks the external library has a namespace as a result you can try as below

use app\models\LineChart;

remove the include and try

Comment: You mean its not necessary to set the path where the external library is located in the project? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference in this new Yii2 version? https://walterebert.com/blog/using-external-php-libraries-with-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using another wraper (https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts). (1) I put the following lines in the require section of the composer.json file: 
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*",
    "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master" (2) And then run in the console the command: composer update

This is the link of the other thread: [How to add google-chart correctly in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483961/how-to-add-google-chart-correctly-in-yii2?noredirect=1#comment54753081_33483961)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.