# How to add google-chart correctly in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have added the extension (a wraper for google chart) "scotthuangzl/yii2-google-chart": "dev-master" to the require section of my composer.json file. However when I call that extension on views\site\myPage.php I have this error: Class 'scotthuangzl\googlechart\GoogleChart' not found. What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

This is the code where I call the google chart:

```
<?php
  use scotthuangzl\googlechart\GoogleChart;

  echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'BarChart',
  'data' => array(
  array('Type', 'Value'),
  array('Var1', $model->avg1),
  .............
  ),
 'options' => array('title' => 'Variable - avg1')));
?>
```

Comment: You Need to update composer after updating adding require section in composer.json

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have this issue when updating the composer:
  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yi
i2[2.0.5, 2.0.6].

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using another wraper (https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts). (1) I put the following lines in the require section of the composer.json file: 
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*",
    "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master" (2) And then run in the console the command: composer update