# Vanilla PHP inside controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Pusher's vanilla PHP library within my controller.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
include( app_path().'/includes/Pusher.php' );

$pusher = new Pusher('KEY', 'KEY', '1234');
$pusher->trigger('bid_channel', 'NewBid', $auction);
```

I know there are Pusher packages but every one of them is broken in some way or another. The `vinkla` packages Facades don't work.

I have used the above code successfully in `routes.php` to test it but when I put it in my controller I get this error:

> FatalErrorException in APIController.php line 40: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Pusher' not found

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing class without namespace to namespaced class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574794/importing-class-without-namespace-to-namespaced-class)

Comment: It's possible to use dependency injection or rename the facade all together to get the *vinkla/pusher* package working.

Comment: @Jeemusu I prefer using Facades. I just don't know how to rename it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912408/renaming-a-facade-conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the class `Pusher` in it's namespace. It doesn't seem to take advantage of specific namespaces, so it's namespace will be the base namespace.

Try:

```
$pusher = new \Pusher('KEY', 'KEY', '123');
```

This is because at the top of your controller file there will be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

This puts the file into the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, so anything in the base namespace will have to have the leading slash which indicates the class is in the base namespace.