# Renaming a facade - conflicts

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

I am trying to use the `vinkla/pusher` package with Laravel 5.1.

It is a common known issue that the facades don't work because of a conflict: https://github.com/vinkla/pusher/issues/2

A solution is to rename the facade.
How would I go about doing this? I know it wouldn't be as simple as renaming the file..

Thanks!