# SOAP Server in TYPO3 6.2 extension

Tags: php, soap, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2 and I want to implement a SOAP Server within my existing extbase extension. Later on I want to be able to push data through a SOAP request which is then saved to a database.
The extensinon key of my plugin is *soap_parking_deck* and the vendor is Comkom. In my extension I have a class *Classes/Service/SOAPService.php* :

```
namespace Comkom\SoapParkingDeck\Service;

class SOAPService {
  public function __construct() {
    try {
      $server = new SOAPServer (
        NULL,
        array (
          'uri' => 'http://localhost/test/SOAPService',
          'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
          'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
        )
      );
      $server->addFunction('helloWorld');
      $server->handle();
    }
    catch (SOAPFault $fault) {
      print $fault->faultstring;
    }
  }

  public function helloWorld() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
}
```

Within the class I'm defining a PHP SOAPServer and a function helloWorld(). But when I try to make a request I get a 404 error.
With the hint of Arek van Schaijk I figured out a solution.
The 404-Error occured because the uri actually has to be the full path to the Server file.

```
namespace Comkom\SoapParkingDeck\Service;

class SOAPService {
  public function helloWorld() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
}

try {
  $server = new \SOAPServer (
    NULL,
    array (
      'uri' => 'http://localhost/test/typo3conf/ext/soap_parking_deck/Classes/Service/SOAPService',
      'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
    )
  );
  $server->setClass('Comkom\SoapParkingDeck\Service\SOAPService');
  $server->handle();
}
catch (\SOAPFault $fault) {
  print $fault->faultstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example can't work since you're trying to call the class `\Comkom\SoapParkingDeck\Service\SOAPServer` instead of `\SoapServer` and `\Comkom\SoapParkingDeck\Service\SOAPFault` instead of `\SoapFault`.

In a namespaced environment you should declare the `\` (backward slash) for calling php- classes (see also [How to use “root” namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593621/how-to-use-root-namespace-of-php)).

**Debugging**

While development you should enable `debug output`, `deprecation logs` and set `logging to info level`. This can be easily done in the install tool under `Configuration presets` => `Development / Production settings` => `Development`.

Please check also always your `apache errorlog` if you deal with rare behavior like white screens, 500 internal server errors etc.

Comment: Thank you form the hints. I'm bugging now with apache errorlog. As soon I have a working result, I'll post it.