# PHP "Exception not found"

Tags: php, exception

I have a somehow funny issue.
While trying to understand why a certain website returns http code 500 to browser, I found the message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MZ\\MailChimpBundle\\Services\\Exception' not found in /var/www/website/vendor/bundles/MZ/MailChimpBundle/Services/MailChimp.php on line 41
```

in apache log.
Looking at the mentioned line:

```
throw new Exception('This bundle needs the cURL PHP extension.');
```

I now understand how to get the site working, but I still wonder why the code for throwing the exception (which would have resulted in a more helpful log message) failed.
What could be the reason?

Comment: The class definition is missing, it's just class not found. Check if the sources contain the actual file and double-check if it's autoloader is configured correctly. As this is related to integration, it might be that this has not been fully tested by the vendor and `\Exception` was meant (PHP's native, global `Exception` class) instead.

Comment: but how can it fail if there's a global class with that name? Would a invokation of the global Exception class look different from this line? (I'm not a PHP pro, so maybe I lack basic knowledge here)

Comment: Yes, it would look like: `throw new \Exception('This bundle ...` as that line is namespaced. It's probably worth you check first if there is that exception class within the bundle code. If not, report a bug for that bundle.

Comment: so, the backslash forces usage of global namespace? If so, pls put this as answer, then I can vote it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [MZMailChimpBundle](https://github.com/miguel250/MZMailChimpBundle) does not contain a class named `Exception` within the `MZ\MailChimpBundle\Services` namespace.

Because of that simple fact and as the error message that the exception should signal is related to an integration problem (check for the curl library) I assume that this is a bug.

The original has meant `\Exception` and not `Exception` here. It's a somewhat common mistake that can happen with namespaces. To fix the file, either alias/import `\Exception` as `Exception`:

```
namespace MZ\MailChimpBundle\Services;
use Exception;
```

and/or change the `new` line in [`MZMailChimpBundle/Services/MailChimp.php`](https://github.com/miguel250/MZMailChimpBundle/blob/master/Services/MailChimp.php):

```
throw new \Exception('This bundle needs the cURL PHP extension.');
```

See as well the related question: [How to use “root” namespace of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6593621/367456) and the one with the same *Class 'Namespace\Example' not found* error message: [Calling a static method from a class in another namespace in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579040/367456).

Comment: Has been [fixed 2012-08-11 in 72297152 by miguel250](https://github.com/miguel250/MZMailChimpBundle/commit/722971523da673353a4a4285574ed914e57a74ef)

Answer (score 3):

Extending @hakre answer you can simplify its usage with:

```
use \Exception as Exception;
```

That way you can throw exceptions without remembering the backslash like:

```
throw new Exception('This bundle needs the cURL PHP extension.');
```

Comment: Just a remark: There is no need to prefix the namespace of `use <namespace> ...` with the backslash "\". Compare with `use Exception;` [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001405/367456) and see [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in the PHP docs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that the line is trying to throw a user defined Exception in the current namespace, not the built-in Exception class of PHP itself