# How call RuntimeException using namesapce in php version 5.5.8

Tags: php, class, runtimeexception

I'm trying to use **RuntimeException**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php

I have this files in the same folder :

*OtherFunctions.php*

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
$Tble = NULL;

function SetTble($tble) {
  global $Tble;
  $Tble = $tble;
}

function GetTble() {
  global $Tble;
  return $Tble;
}

function Funct0($Str0, $Str1) {
  return $Str0 == $Str1;
}

function Funct1($Arg) {
  return "The Value is ".$Arg;
}
//... from 0 to 16
function Funct16($Arg) {
  return "The Value is ".$Arg;
}
?>
```

**How to call all functions contained in this file?**

In one class File *SubClass.php* I have this:

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
class SubClass {
  public $CArg = "";
  function FnClass($Arg) {
    return "FnClass:The Value is from SubClass".$Arg;
  }
}
?>
```

In other class File *LeadClass.php*
I have this:

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
require_once("SubClass.php");
class LeadClass {
  public function __construct($Name) {
    echo("_._<br>");
    $NewSC = new SubClass();
    $NewSC->CArg = $Name;
    SetTble($Name);
    echo("ini:GetTble():".GetTble().":end<br>");
    echo("ini:".$NewSC->FnClass($Name).":end<br>");
  }
  public function getName() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error Ever !<br>");
  }
}
?>
```

Using all code *CallerNS.php*

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
require_once("LeadClass.php");
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
$NewSC = new LeadClass("first");
$NewSC->getName();
if (Funct0("strings", "strings")) {
  print("same strings<br>");
}
?>
```

Here my error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Pack\sp\RuntimeException' not found in C:...\LeadClass.php on line 15**

In other version of *CallerNS.php*

```
<?php
use Pack\sp;
require_once("LeadClass.php");
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
if (Funct0("strings", "strings")) {
  print("same strings<br>");
}
$NewSC = new LeadClass("first");
$NewSC->getName();
?>
```

The error message:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function Funct0() in C:...\CallerNS.php on line 5**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a standard answer, check your PHP version. The documentation for `RuntimeException` requires at **least** PHP 5.1 or higher.

You may do this via `phpinfo()`, or `php -v` in your console (if you are running it locally and have access to php via. PATH)

Edit: [This question and answer seem related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000539/php-exception-not-found). Essentially, it is also your namespace causing the mixup. Essentially, it is looking for a namespaced RuntimeException class (see your error).

Since you're using namespaces, you will need to reference back to the root namespace (`\`) any time you want to use the native classes.

You may want to try:

```
throw new \RuntimeException('...'); // The '\' tells PHP to use the root namespace.
```

Second Edit:

As for your second issue, that is a matter of your code order.
In your `CallerNS.php` file, you're declaring to use the namespace `Pack\sp`, **and then** including your namespaced files into your code. This won't work because you will need to have the namespace already declared before you can use it.

You can either include the files first, or use `\Pack\sp\Funct0(...)` instead.

Comment: print("Current PHP version:". phpversion());  -->>> My Current PHP version:5.5.8

Comment: Edited again for second answer.